# simple way to confirm if a video has a black or transparent background

Tags: ffmpeg

What is a method of determining if you are seeing a black or transparent background when working with videos without using anything other than the Windows OS?

Comment: Assuming the background is consistent across the video, step 1 - check the pix_fmt, if it does not have alpha channel, then the background is opaque. else step 2 - read the first frame with `-f rawvideo -pix_fmt rgba` and inspect background pixels' alpha values.

Comment: What do you mean with the background being consistent? The non-transparent part of the video does move sometimes, but otherwise the background is consistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an excellent method! In Windows, you can get a thumbnail out of your video by "zooming in" in the explorer. Make the icons for each file in the current folder as big as possible, like this

[image: an image called result.mov of a picture with fog over a transparent background and an image called result.mp4 of a picture with fog where the background is black.]